# Add unique ids to a set of consecutive rows to define blocks/groups based on specified first row of group

Tags: r, block, group

I have a set of data (column col) with dedicated "groups" based on consecutive rows (column line) and a first record for each group. The first record of each group is always identified by a status id called "0" followed by status id's "2" or "4" refering to different types of information (column status).

Here's a typical example:

| line | col | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0 |
| 2 | b | 2 |
| 3 | c | 0 |
| 4 | d | 2 |
| 5 | e | 4 |
| 6 | f | 0 |
| 7 | g | 4 |
| 8 | h | 2 |
| 9 | i | 0 |
| 10 | j | 2 |

For further data analysis an additional id for each group is needed (column id) - the modified data frame should look like this:

| line | col | status | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | c | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | d | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | e | 4 | 2 |
| 6 | f | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | g | 4 | 3 |
| 8 | h | 2 | 3 |
| 9 | i | 0 | 4 |
| 10 | j | 2 | 4 |

Please note line 6:8 where the status "4" follows "0" instead of the "typical" status id "2"...

I tried to use such base R functions as cumsum and similar approaches:
in this case adding unique id's is only possible if the status id's are always in ascending order.
Is there an elegant way to use a base R approach to provide unique id's based on a dedicated first status id's for each group?

Comment: Something like `cumsum(x$status == 0)` ?

Comment: ...embarassing how easy it can be... thank you!